# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'Sa' in vs code

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I have bee trying to connect my .aspx table to a table in sql server and this hasn't been  working out because:

I'm not quite sure if it's a problem with the code itself of just with sql server. I even made sure the database is able to allow remote connections and other troubleshooting.

Here's my source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Thato_Maenge.index
{
    public partial class User_Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=PRFAB-PCLAB2-40\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=proagro;User ID=Sa;Password=***********";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Clear();
            }
        }

        protected void btnsignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtfname.Text == "" || txtlname.Text == "" || txtuser.Text == "" || txtemail.Text == "" || txtid.Text == "" || txtphone.Text == "" || txtpass.Text == "")
                lblError.Text = "Please Fill In All Required Fields.";

            else if (txtpass.Text != txtconfirm.Text)
                lblError.Text = "Passwords Do Not Match. Try Again.";
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("userReg", sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", Convert.ToInt32(hfuserid.Value == ""?"0": hfuserid.Value));
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtfname.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtlname.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtuser.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", ddgender.SelectedValue);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNo", txtid.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtphone.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpass.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Clear();
                lblSuccess.Text = "Signing up successful";

            }
        }

        void Clear()
        {
            txtfname.Text = txtlname.Text = txtuser.Text = txtemail.Text = txtemail.Text = txtphone.Text = txtpass.Text = "";
            hfuserid.Value = "";
            lblSuccess.Text = lblError.Text = "";
        }
    }
}


 

I'm not sure how to handle this as I'm quite new to programming.
```

Comment: As you are getting a login error check what the actual authentication error in the SQL Server logs, as the error passed to theapplication error is intentionally ambiguous. If you don't understand that error, [edit] your question to include that error.

Comment: As you are new - please read the following: https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/#:~:text=The%20Problem%20with%20Addwithvalue&text=Parameters%20in%20SQL%20Server%20are,about%20the%20intended%20parameter%20type.

Comment: And this: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Your code shouldn't be using the `sa` user. Create a user for your program and grant the necessary permissions to the user. There may be more secure ways to connect, depending on your environment.

Comment: Hi, have you got any updates?

Answer (score 0):

Login failed for User is a general sql error message.

Check your sql Server connection string.

Put SQL Server in mixed mode authentication.

Mixed mode authentication:
[image]
[image]

Note: The server must be stopped and re-started before this will take effect.

Integrated Security=SSPI means that its using the windows account which is setup for the Anonymous User in IIS.

The connection string should be:

```
Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=PERSONAL;User ID=personal; Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;
```

You can refer to this link.
http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/failed.htm